# add 2 new columns with values present in row headers

Tags: excel, vba

H,
i have an inventory sheet in this format.(provided image below, did not know how to add table over here). The company name and category are not in separate columns. instead the are listed in the product column. i want to add 2 additional columns, one for company and one for category, and add details to every row correspondingly.

original format

[image: ORIGINAL FORMAT]

desired format

[image: DESIRED FORMAT]

what would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Scan down the first column using conditionals like `If Cells(i,1).Value Like  "Company:" Then ... ElseIf  If Cells(i,1).Value  Like "Product:" Then ... Else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want, it assumes your data starts in column A:

```
Sub ChangeFormat()
Dim CompanyName As String, Catgory As String, LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For X = 2 To LR
    If X > LR Then Exit For
    If Left(UCase(Range("A" & X).text), 8) = "COMPANY:" Then
        CompanyName = Trim(Right(Range("A" & X).text, Len(Range("A" & X).text) - 8))
        Rows(X).Delete
        LR = LR - 1
    End If
    If Left(UCase(Range("A" & X).text), 9) = "CATEGORY:" Then
        Category = Trim(Right(Range("A" & X).text, Len(Range("A" & X).text) - 9))
        Rows(X).Delete
        LR = LR - 1
    End If
    Range("E" & X).Formula = CompanyName
    Range("F" & X).Formula = Category
Next
End Sub
```

It scans through and when it finds one of the headings it assigns that value to the variable then deletes the row, if it finds neither then it assumes it is data and posts the Company and Category to columns E and F (I think Catagory is spelled wrong but I went with your spelling of it).

Make sure you back up your data before running this as it will modify what you have.

Comment: just tried this macro. it worked flawless. if it could create the 2 new columns after the last column in the sheet it would be even better. i forgot to mention the no. of columns on the actual sheet were 7. not a big deal though. i wish i could vote up the answer.

Comment: You can change these lines from E and F respectively to the wanted columns: `Range("E" & X).Formula = CompanyName` `Range("F" & X).Formula = Category` or alternatively you can use something like `cells(X,columns.Count).end(xltoleft).offset(0,1).Formula = CompanyName` and `cells(X,columns.Count).end(xltoleft).offset(0,1).Formula = Category` This will detect the last used column in that row and offset by one column. The risk here is that if there is a row that doesn't have data in all columns it will fail it, you can use a static row 1 to counter this instead of X and offset the second one by 2.

Comment: did that and everything was perfect

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help :) please mark the answer as correct if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a macro to do the task. You can change the name of the sheet as indicated in the code.

```
Sub InventoryReformat()
Dim ar
Dim i As Long
Dim wRow As Long
Dim sTxt As String, sCompany As String, sCategory As String
Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet

Set wsS = Sheets("SOURCE_DATA")                                            'Change as required
Set wsD = Sheets("DESTINATION")                                            'Change as required

ar = wsS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value                                   'Change start cell as required
wRow = 1                                                                   'Change first destination row as required
With wsD
    .Cells(wRow, 1).Resize(1, 6) = Split("PRODUCT|COST PRICE|SALE PRICE|TAX|CATEGORY|COMPANY", "|")
    wRow = wRow + 1
    For i = 2 To UBound(ar, 1)
        sTxt = ar(i, 1)
        If InStr(1, sTxt, "Company") > 0 Then
            sCompany = Trim(Split(sTxt, ":")(1))
        Else
            If InStr(1, sTxt, "Category") > 0 Then
                sCategory = Trim(Split(sTxt, ":")(1))
            Else
                .Cells(wRow, 1) = ar(i, 1)
                .Cells(wRow, 2) = ar(i, 2)
                .Cells(wRow, 3) = ar(i, 3)
                .Cells(wRow, 4) = ar(i, 4)
                .Cells(wRow, 5) = sCategory
                .Cells(wRow, 6) = sCompany
                wRow = wRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    .Cells(wRow - 1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
End With
End Sub
```

.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: just tried this aswell. there seems to be an issue. it is not capturing all "COMPANY: " rows.
it did fine for the 1st company. total 14 row header with "CATEGORY: ". as the company changed on the 15th row header in the sheet with "COMPANY: " at row 680, it was skipped and previous company name was copied and it went on skipping a total of 14 row headers with "COMPANY: ". it then captured the 15th one, went fine for that single company and then again copied the same company name for the next ones